# Conditional subtracting in google scripts in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried to have a google script subtract a number from a cell based on input from a google form to a google sheet.

I am very new to google scripts.

Many thanks to any help. it is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the number is on Question 1:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(sh.getRange('A1').getValue()-Number(e.values[1]));
}
```

[On Form Submit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)